# GLSL shader analysis toolkit

Tags: opengl-es, benchmarking, analysis

I want to implement an GLSL shader analysis toolkit on mobile devices which I have little Idea about it.
The idea of the GLSL shader analysis toolkit is to run this program on different mobile devices and then to give artists a straightforward impression which operation is the most expensive: FShader, VShader, Rasterisation or Band-width. But I do not know how to measure VShader (The idea of VShader part is to measure what's the max vertex number a mobile devices can support, given a shader).

In short, I am looking for help about an Opengl benchmark on mobile devices.

PS, I have implemented the analysis on FShader by drawing many screen quads with a given shader, minus the performance of drawing many screen quads with a void FShader. Depth writes and depth test are off during the test. I just want a general idea of the cost and do not want to involve with compiler and hard-ware things.

The Best

Comment: Ask your tutor if the assignment is not clear. It's your internship, not ours.

Answer (score 1):

> I knew it might make little sense to measure a shader in this naive way

It doesn't. It's entirely possible to condition static models in software, so on some vendors entirely off-screen geometry may not make it to the GPU at all if the driver can determine that an entire draw operation is redundant.

***Benchmarks should always measure what real applications actually do, otherwise you have no idea if what you are actually measuring is representative of reality.***

Real applications don't render all of their geometry outside of the frustum, so it's highly likely you are hitting an optimized fast path which will skip at least some of the geometry related pipeline (e.g. computing only position, and not the rest of the vertex shader, or early discard of entire draw calls).

Ditto for you benchmark which is rendering lots of layers - for mobile GPUs (most of which are tile-based to some extent) tend to have some limits on number of concurrent layers before you start seeing at least some performance roll off. (because real applications don't render lots and lots of layers, so why waste hardware supporting it). If you want a slower workload then either render to a large off-screen render target, or multiple smaller (but not too small ones).